# Cannot set the view from activity android

Tags: java, android, set

I am facing a strange problem suddenly in android. I am creating layout .xml file in res>layout but from a class that extends activity, I can not access it. I have done this several a time but I can not figure out this strange problem. I restarted the eclipse, even the computer but no. When I go for setting the contentView it says something as below :

```
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method
```

That is let I have created an xml file at res>layout named "whynot.xml" and from a activity when I try to set it like

```
setContentView(R.layout.whynot);
```

It shows red mark below and the above message.

Answer (score 0):

you have to `extends Activity` and call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`  in the `onCreate`. For each callback of the Activity's lifecycle is mandatory to call its `super`

Comment: I have done it but still it is not working. I am trying this with the older project I did, but even then it is not working ... my head is just exploding and idea ???? @blackbelt

Comment: post the whole onCreate and the error you are getting as well

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, 
`must override or implement a supertype method`

you need the `super` call like

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);  // here
    setContentView(...);
    ...
}
```